# Drag animation for the images

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have no experience what so ever on how to create a animation

I need to create such animation

[image]

any help is appreciated

Thanks and regards
Aashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is plain Drag and Drop, it can be done with or without animation.

If you are developing for Android 3.0 or higher you are in luck, Google has made framework which makes Drag and Drop a Child's play, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) to know more.

Here are a few tutorials to get you started:

1. [Tutorial 1](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/drag-and-drop-honeycombics.html)
2. [Tutorial 2](http://codingjunkie.net/android-drag-and-drop-part1/)
3. [Tutorial 3](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)

If you are developing for API level lesser than 3.0 then you are largely on your own to develop drag and drop functionality, well [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the help but not quite what I am looking for I am able to drag and drop I just need to create this animation

Comment: What do you need the animation for, in drag and drop we can re-size the image on ACTION_DOWN event and also color it so that it looks animated...